# How can I know the Keycloak version?

Tags: keycloak

In the older KeyCloak versions, we could use:

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh -version
```

This would print the version info.

But in newer versions it seems that this `standalone.sh` is removed.

How can I get the version in newer versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
cat version.txt
```

in the root folder that contains Keycloak.

Or

```
./bin/kc.sh --version
```

and get as an output for example:

```
Keycloak 20.0.3
(..)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can view the version in the UI as well. You need to select the "master" realm first and then click on the Keycloak logo in the top-left corner. It will show something like this:

[image: Screenshot of the server info of Keycloak]

In this case, the Keycloak version is 21.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

In bash I get the local (i.e. installed) version from version.txt with:

```
localKeycloak=`cat /opt/keycloak/version.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
```

(you may need to change /opt/keycloak according to to the actual folder in your system)

then I check the latest version on GitHub with:

```
latestKeycloak=`curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/keycloak/keycloak/releases/latest | jq -r .name`
```

(You'll need to install jq if not already present in your system). You can then use the two versions in a shell script to do do something like sending an email, etc.

```
if [ "${localKeycloak}" = "${latestKeycloak}" ]
then
    echo "Keycloak installed version (${localKeycloak}) equals latest version online (${latestKeycloak})."
    # do something
else
    echo "Keycloak new version available: ${latestKeycloak}"
    # do something else
fi
```